# PayPal returned success but amount not credited

Tags: php, paypal

I integrated PayPal to a custom website. Post integration, did a transaction test. All params seemed to pass through correctly. Made the transaction payment (for trial basis kept amount as low as $ 0.02) and PayPal perfectly executed it and redirected it to the url that i had defined for success trn. However, neither does the seller paypal account show the turn nor has $0.02 been debited from the buyer's paypal id.

Kindly let me know of the mistake if any. Under what circumstances is such a thing expected.

P.S: The balance in the sellers account is $0. Is it possible that because of the negative value, the turn did not go through? ($ +0.02 - $0.3) : 0.3 being the commissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of things.
Try catching the response sent by paypal and putting it into a log file.

Simply do this:

```
ob_start();
print_r($_POST);
$data = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents('log.txt',$data,FILE_APPEND);
```

This will help you in determining what the problem is. A lot of times, the transaction is in "pending" mode.